# bitbucket looses PR review history in case of rebase

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request, history, review

We use bitbucket at work.
I have an issue that I don't know how to solve.

Whenever I create a PR, bit bucket will show the diff for people to review it.
Modifications yet to be reviewed will appear in bold, whereas modifications already reviewed will appear not in bold.
If I push a commit to my branch, adding new modifications, these will be displayed in bold as well.
Once nothing remains in bold, people can mark the PR as approved.

Now, the issue is: if I rebase my branch while it is under review, then all PR review history is lost.
Every modification in the branch is displayed in bold again.
That is quite annoying, especially for a big PR.

I would expect that all patches of my branch that did not cause any conflict when rebased to remain in bold; and that only the conflict resolutions to appear in bold in order to be reviewed.

But if some code changes that are totally unrelated to my own branch have been pushed to master, and I want to rebase my branch on top of master, then I would expect bitbucket to keep the PR review history.

Is this achievable?

Thanks,

- Julien